# Contact Us Email Options

Tags: magento2, contact-us

Is there a way how to set multiple recipients on Magento 2 Contacts, right now it only allows to set single email.

http://prntscr.com/l3f158

Thanks,
JM

Comment: You have to create a separate field to achieve this functionality as this field is used in many modules so it will require you to customize at many locations. Instead, you can add a separate field for multiple email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve, this requirement, there are two section, where you have to work.

- First, you have created a new field at system  configuration where
  you can put multiple emails.
- Second, you have to  change  `Magento\Contact\Model\Mail::send`  behaviour  base  using around plugin

So, first create a module which has a system.xml file at `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/etc/adminhtml/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="contact">
            <group id="email">
                <field id="recipient_emails" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Send Emails To Multiple Email</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Around Plugin**

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{MOdule}\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;

class EmailPlugin {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $contactsConfig;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    private $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StateInterface
     */
    private $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param ConfigInterface $contactsConfig
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param StoreManagerInterface|null $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface  $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    ) {
        $this->contactsConfig = $contactsConfig;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }




    public function aroundSend($replyTo, array $variables)
    {
        /** @see \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::validatedParams() */
        $replyToName = !empty($variables['data']['name']) ? $variables['data']['name'] : null;
        $to = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('contact/email/recipient_emails', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($variables)
                ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
                ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient())
                ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
        } finally {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        }
    }

 }
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Contact\Model\Email">
        <plugin name="multiple-email-receipts" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Plugin\EmailPlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

The code is not tested, give basic of the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate config for other email address then you can create after plugin of

```
emailRecipient()
```

method located in

`vendor/magento/module-contact/Model/Config.php` file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. Just figured it out that I just extend the core magento contact, and instead of commenting out **validate-email** under etc/adminhtml/system.xml, I just replace it **required-entry**

Thanks.